# Pygame isn't drawing anything when I go pixel by pixel

Tags: python, pygame

I an attempting to make a python program that will display the mandelbrot set, and I am attempting to render it pixel-by-pixel, but it is showing only black.

I am running python 3.7 and I am using pygame version 1.9.4. The only thing that is not working is the rendering.

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,1000))
carryOn=True
pressed=False
for i in range(len(mandelbrot)):
    for j in range(len(mandelbrot[i])):
        if j:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (j, i, 1,1))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),(j, i, 1,1))
pygame.display.flip()
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn=False

    pygame.time.Clock().tick(40)
pygame.quit()
```

mandelbrot is defined earlier in my code

I expected to get an image of the mandlebrot set, but instead I got just a black pygame window.

Comment: Shouldn't that test be: `if ( mandelbrot[i][j] ):` instead of `if j:`

Comment: What is `mandelbrot` defined as? Also, just for testing, try modifying your for loops to be: `for i in range(len(win_width)):\n\t for j in range(len(win_height):\n\t\t pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (j, i, 1,1))`

Comment: Mandelbrot is defined as a list of true/false

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the line width on your rectangles.  It defaults to 0, and so I think pygame won't draw a single-pixel filled rectangle with no outline.

Adding a width of 1 at the end makes the pixels draw:

`pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),(j, i, 1, 1), 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You should put your drawing functions and flip() in the while loop,
if you're drawing to the screen.

```
#I assume this is your main loop?
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn=False

    # clear the screen with black
    screen.fill((0,0,0)

    # assume mandelbrot is a 2D-Array
    for i in range(len(mandelbrot)):
        for j in range(len(mandelbrot[i])):
            if j:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (j, i, 1,1))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255),(j, i, 1,1))

    # display.flip should be in the while loop
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```